# HTTP::Proxy, checking if the transfer was successful on the server-side

Tags: perl, proxy

I'm using [HTTP::Proxy](http://search.cpan.org/~book/HTTP-Proxy-0.25/lib/HTTP/Proxy.pm) to check the behaviour of a client-server application. I already made a filter to deliver arbitrary content to the client.

The application I've to test is [cvmfs](http://cernvm.cern.ch/portal/filesystem). It's a software that uses standard http connection to mount a remote filesystem. We need to check what happen when the server sends a file bigger than cvmfs cache partition. And we would like to check if cvmfs needs to download the whole file before discarding it or if it stops as soon as it's clear that the file is wrong.

The client is expecting a 10mb file, while the server will send it a 100mb file. Of course, the client will recognize the fake file and will not mount the repository. I would like to check if the client stops to load after 10mb or if it loads the whole file before closing the connection and I have to check it on the server-side.

So, once the server starts sending the file (this work will be done by HTTP::Proxy that will intercept the call and will serve a fake file), I want to know when the client stop to download it.

Is there a way to do it? It will be enough to know if the transfer was successful or not, although it could be useful to directly check how many mb were transferred.

EDIT

This is the filter I'm using to log transferred data (I'm using the two proxy approach suggested) and it does what I want. Unfortunately, it works properly only for plain text file. How can I accomplish the same for executable files (I'm exporting executable files)?

```
package Filters::RecordTransfer;

######################################
# This filter is intended to be used for response
######################################

use strict;
use warnings;
use HTTP::Proxy::BodyFilter::simple;

our $body = HTTP::Proxy::BodyFilter::simple->new (
    sub {
        my ( $self, $dataref, $message, $protocol, $buffer ) = @_;
        my $record_file = '/tmp/transferred_data';

        if (-e $record_file) {
            my $fh;
            open($fh, '<', $record_file);
            my $actual_size = $fh->getline;
            close($fh);
            my $new_size = $actual_size + (length($$dataref));
            open($fh, '>', $record_file);
            print $fh $new_size;
            close($fh);
        }
        else {
            open (my $fh, '>', $record_file);
            print $fh length($$dataref);
            close($fh);
        }
    }
);

1;
```

Comment: I'm confused. Who is sending whom stuff? Please try to be describe this a little bit more concise.

Comment: I didn't think it could be useful because my question didn't depend on this... however, I added a little explanation (but the question is a bit redundant now).

Comment: At least now we understand what you meant by 'repository'. That was unclear. Thank you. Anyway... how about summing up the `lenght()` of all the messages that go through the filter? Or is that to simple? I cannot test right now.

Comment: @simbabque, I've added the filter I'm actually using to replace the whole file. I don't think your solution is suitable (at least with this filter) as far as the filter received empty data at the beginning and only at the end it replace it with the whole file. If you have a better way to create the filter, it's welcome.

Comment: I wasn't sure what you meant. I thought you'd already get the large file, but it seems you want to trick the client by mangling the actual connection. I was not aware of that. I think you cannot use the actual filter to do that. Maybe you could try to sniff the connection between the client and the proxy, or you could use another proxy to check how much is being transfered.

Comment: @simbabque, I want to avoid that misconfigured server (or a malicious one) could send a wrong file that is above the cache size for cvmfs. This is why I'm replacing the request. I will give a try to the two proxy approach, it seems promising to me. :)

Comment: @simbabque, Hi, your solution with length works well with plain/text file, but I'm working with executables... do you know how can I accomplish the same for executable files (it could be great be able to do it for general files, for example dividing it in byte)? I did an edit to show the filter I'm using by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the file the wrong way. You must set the appropriate [IO layer](http://p3rl.org/PerlIO).

```
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
$$dataref = read_file '/tmp/cvmfs.faulty', { binmode => ':raw' };
```

---

When the response finishes, the `$count` variable will have the number of octets gone through the filter.

```
use HTTP::Proxy qw();
use HTTP::Proxy::BodyFilter::simple qw();

my $count;
my $body = HTTP::Proxy::BodyFilter::simple->new(sub {
    $count += length ${ $_[1] };
    warn $count;
});

my $proxy = HTTP::Proxy->new(port => 3128);
$proxy->push_filter(response => $body, mime => '*/*');
$proxy->start;
```

Comment: Sorry, din't understand this solution. In this way I can set `$$dataref` to my faulty file. And I will do it at first because I need to send this file. But then, I have this file splitted in many data chunks and I would like to retrieve the size, in bytes, of these chunks. How could I use your example to do it?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about with "then" and "chunks". I was referring to the code in [revision 4](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11392193/4) - that's the wrong way to read the `/tmp/cvmfs.faulty` file.

Comment: I noticed and I will change it. :) But the question was about discovering how many bytes were transferred before the client recognize the file as faulty. Actually I'm trying to realize it with two proxies. The first one will replace the whole body response with cvmfs.faulty (using your system) while the second proxy will receive this file, so `$$dataref` will be each time a part of this file. I would like to understand how long this part is when `$$dataref` doesn't point to a text file (in which case I can do it with `length()`).

Comment: Sorry, but that works only with text files (i.e. it works if I ask for an index.html file). But it doesn't work with, for example, an image file. I just tried copy pasting your script, launching it, connecting through telnet and asking some files. Actually, it seems the whole filter is ignored for non-text files. Answering this, I think the question could be considered solved.

Comment: Set the [`mime` parameter](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Proxy#FILTERS), default is to filter text types only. See edit above.